# Input and button widths just occupy 100% but dont appear next to each other

Tags: css

I have a yellow div and below a input with background red and a buttoun with background gray. I want that the input and button appear next to each other but its not working. But its strange because I have the input with 80% and the button with 20% and both without margins so its strange that is not working. Do you know where is the issue?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
}

input,
select,
textarea,
button {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

select,
input,
button {
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

a img {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/*CONTAINER*/

.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 64%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.box {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.box-search {
  width: 23.3%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-small {
  width: 22.75%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.filter-city {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.filter-city input {
  width: 80%;
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.filter-city button {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  color: $color-white;
  background-color: $color-primary;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box box-small filter_results">
      <div style="width:100%; background-color:yellow; height:40px;">

      </div>

      <div class="filter-city">
        <input class="m_top" value="Test" type="text">
        <button><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/v2j6uetz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is caused to two things:

1. White space between the input and button.

   Inline and inline-block elements allow other elements to exist next to them on a line, which includes spaces. A line break between the two elements introduces a space between them that isn't accounted for by your percentages.
2. Horizontal button padding greater than its computed width.

   The button has `padding:15px`, which sets both horizontal and vertical padding. But the button in your example is less than 15px wide so, even with `box-sizing:border-box`, the button's width is pushed larger than your percentage.

Here's a working example:

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  width: 64%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.box {
  float: left;
}
.box-search {
  width: 23.3%;
}
.box-small {
  width: 22.75%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.filter-city input,
.filter-city button {
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.filter-city input {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
}

.filter-city button {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box box-small filter_results">
      <div style="width:100%; background-color:yellow; height:40px;"></div>
      <div class="filter-city">
        <input class="m_top" value="Test" type="text"><button>Test</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "display" in Firebug or Chrome Developer tools? IIRC, input is at default a block-level element, so applying a property like "display: inline-block;" to the necessary input should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `float : left` on the divs that need to be next to each other and the containing div.

Answer (score -1):

If you just add

```
filter-city {
    display: flex;
    ....
}
```

It should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/g97qf57o/

To be honest I am not entirely sure why this works, but in my experience flexbox can solve most layout problems.